# matplotlib: Get the colormap array

Tags: matplotlib, color-mapping

I am new to matplotlib, and have get stuck in colormaps.

In matplotlib how do I get the whole array of RGB colors for a specific colormap, let's say for "hot". For example if I was in MATLAB I would have just done this:

```
# in matlab
c = hot(256);
disp(c)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 28):

You can look up the values by calling the colormap as a function, and it accepts numpy arrays to query many values at once:

```
In [12]: from matplotlib import cm
In [13]: cm.hot(range(256))
Out[13]: 
array([[ 0.0416    ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.05189484,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.06218969,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       ..., 
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  0.96911762,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  0.98455881,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ]])
```

Answer (score -6):

Got it! So you just go in the command window of your Matlab and type

cmap = colormap(nameOfTheColormapYouWant)

Possible colormap in Matlab are: parula, jet, hsv, hot, cool, spring, summer,autumn,winter, gray, bone, copper, pink, lines, colorcube, prism, flag.

You get a matrix where each row is the color code used for the colormap.

Comment: This is how to get the RGB array in `Matlab`. OP wants to get the RGB array in python's `matplotlib` package. Please read the question next time.